# Any one using Magento EE can see correct related products and up-sell in product pages?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento EE now, I just want to ask any one using Magento EE can see correct related products and up-sell in product page?
 This is a product's page 's screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT6x9.png

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to see but can't? Try posting some screenshots or your actual code. Otherwise it may be hard for anyone to help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added a screenshot of a product page. But actually my problem is that when I turn on my full page cache, the related products in the current page will be same with related products from the last product page I open, but these two product pages should have different related products. Have you encountered same problem before?